# Ion Video Forever on Windows Server

Tags: drivers, video, windows-server-2008-r2, webcam, windows-server

I'm trying to get an [Ion Video Forever](https://www.ionaudio.com/products/details/video-transfer) (composite video capture card) working on windows server 2008R2. Currently, I cannot start a video stream from that device. Drivers have been installed from the provided cd.

To aid troubleshooting, I've also been using a microsoft lifecam webcam to see what windows server is capable of. After installing the desktop experience pack, windows server is now able to happily stream video from a usb webcam, but video from the ion device still wont show.

I know the ion device is working as connecting to a windows 8.1 laptop it works correctly and I can see the video streaming through it. Therefore I'm wondering what the ion device requires above and beyond a normal webcam.

From this [forum post](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-media/msg63928.html) we learn the below

> The CD-ROM in the packet is apparently a driver set for an "ezcap"
> device ("Ezcap Video Grabber"), the INF file suggests it's an EM2860
> series chip. For a laugh, I did this:
>
> sudo modprobe em28xx card=9
>
> echo eb1a 5124 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/em28xx/new_id
>
> Which has the effect of loading the EM28xx driver with cardtype forced
> to 9 (which seems to be a generic EM2860-based device ID), then adding
> the new device ID (temporarily) to the module.

**Philip Pemberton - May 2013**

Looking online, this gives an indication of what the device is underneath (empia em2860), but I'm still struggling to find examples of it being used in a windows environment or get ideas what's also required to run on a server version of windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible on windows server as this requires components from both the desktop experience pack (available on 2008R2) **and** the "Broadcast Driver Architecture" (BDA) (**removed in windows server 2008R2** - now only in client windows builds).

This is why it works on Windows 8, but not 2008R2 with the desktop pack.

Best option would be to build a Windows 10 box as a makeshift home server.